Add an aria-label and append to an external link with JQuery
OK folks, I'm trying to take all links which open in new windows and add an aria-label attribute to them which contains the link text plus "opens in new tab".
So I want to take this:
<a href="..." target="_blank">My link</a>

and turn it into:
<a href="..." target="_blank" aria-label="My link - opens in new tab">My link</a>

I think I'm on the right track, but it's not quite right. Here's what I have:
$('body a[target="_blank"]:not([aria-label])').attr("aria-label", (.textContent) + "- opens in new tab" });


This expression is a syntax error:
(.textContent) + "- opens in new tab"

Do you mean that for each matching element you want to use its text content for this attribute?  In that case you'd likely need to loop over the elements so you have a context in which to access that value.  Something like this:
$('body a[target="_blank"]:not([aria-label])').each(function () {
    $(this).attr("aria-label", $(this).text() + "- opens in new tab");
});

Or if you specifically want to use the .textContent property on the element, you can reference the DOM element itself as the second parameter to the callback function:
$('body a[target="_blank"]:not([aria-label])').each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).attr("aria-label", el.textContent + "- opens in new tab");
});


The latter. And it works perfectly. Thanks Dave.
